# SIEM streaming over TCP, getting multiple messages put into one event

Tags: c++, linux, tcp, stream

Adjusting question:
SIEM is a management system that takes syslog and other types of log messages and allows an admin to search, combine, and report on logs in ways that helps them better understand what is going on.  I am working with Splunk and sending Syslog (CEF) formatted messages to Splunk.  When I send two messages to splunk, that appear in the same message as seen here.

> <1286>Sep 16, 2014 2:07:38 PM dbrLnxRv CEF:0|MyCompany|MyApp|2.0|Malicious|6|FileName eicar.cab dname=www.csm-testcenter.org dst=10.204.64.137 dpt=8080 prot=HTTP src=10.204.82.168 spt=49809 suser="" xAuthenticatedUser="" requestMethod=GET requestClientApplication="" reason=0-1492-EICARFile.Detection_Test.Web.RTSS request=http://www.csm-testcenter.org/download/archives/cab/eicar.cab AnalysisType="" ThreatName=EICARFile  ThreatReason=0-1492-EICARFile.Detection_Test.Web.RTSS Category=128 Direction=inbound Manual=1 TicketNumber=0 FileType=unknown FileHash=654ec5ae29c1718501af794822663da40aec51fc FileSize=168 Status=completed SessionId=79421 TransactionId=5
>   <1286>Sep 16, 2014 2:07:39 PM dbrLnxRv CEF:0|MyCompany|MyApp|2.0|Malicious|6|FileName eicar.cab dname=www.csm-testcenter.org dst=85.214.28.69 dpt=80 prot=HTTP src=10.204.64.137 spt=40378 suser="" xAuthenticatedUser="" requestMethod=GET requestClientApplication="" reason=0-1492-EICARFile.Detection_Test.Web.RTSS request=http://www.csm-testcenter.org/download/archives/cab/eicar.cab AnalysisType="" ThreatName=EICARFile  ThreatReason=0-1492-EICARFile.Detection_Test.Web.RTSS Category=128 Direction=inbound Manual=1 TicketNumber=0 FileType=unknown FileHash=654ec5ae29c1718501af794822663da40aec51fc FileSize=168 Status=completed SessionId=79432 TransactionId=3

My questions is, how can I make them appear in separate blocks.
Currently have CR/LF between each message (verified by looking at the TCP transaction using Wireshark).  Tried adding a NULL too, did not make a difference.
I know I am not down to the MS in the date/Time field, is that an issue?
Is there a message ID I am missing that will force Splunk to separate the messages?
Other ideas?
(When sending via UDP, the each event appears in it's own message)
Also tried disabling the nagle algo. and still same issue.

---

I created a custom C++ app to send SIEM messages from my data source to Splunk.  If I send 6 SIEM messages over a socket at one time with each message is separated by a CR/LF (I also tried adding a NULL between the messages), Splunk puts them into one single event.  What should I send to cause the messages to be in unique events?  I've look everywhere for the spec on the SIEM protocol and have not found and binary base documents on the actual protocol.

Comment: There is no such thing as a message in TCP. It can fragment or combine transmissions as much as it likes.

Answer (score 1):

TCP is 'stream' protocol and not message oriented. It does not maintain message boundaries. What one sends is not guaranteed to be read in the same way. It is upto the applications above TCP to interpret the bytes and form 'messages'

UDP on the hand maintains message boundaries. One `sendto` of X bytes will translate to `recvfrom` of X bytes. Though UDP will not gurantee that the message will reach the receiver.

The above stated reason is what you are witnessing. Multiple `send`s translating to single `recv` and in UDP the opposite.

Comment: I know TCP is a streaming protocol.  Most protocols have some way to indicate the end of one message (event) and the start of another.  This could include the length of the message at the beginning (so one knows how much to read off the wire before the next message starts) or with a CR LF and or NULL at the end of the message so one knows that the single event has ended and another one starts.  The question I am trying to ask is what in the stream tells SIEM that one event has been sent and another is about to begin?

Comment: As I had mentioned, it is upto the application using TCP to 'form' messages out of what TCP gives. The message length , demarkers like CRLF are for the application to take care. Not TCP

Comment: Client and server should agree on what are the markers for the start of message and end of message. As per that understanding they should interpret the stream

Comment: Prabhu, that is what I am asking, I cannot find a document on the SIEM protocol so I want to know what is the agreed upon marker,

Comment: @HandyManDan You're writing the program to send these messages over TCP, so you should create the protocol that provides message support. TCP doesn't support messages, you need messages, so *you* need to make a message protocol.

Comment: @HandyManDan You're not going to get far with sending anything over a protocol you don't know anything about, are you? If your question is about the 'SIEM protocol', whatever that is, if anything, you should adjust your question accordingly, or delete this and start a new one. From what I read quickly about Splunk it supports quite a number of protocols but none of them is called SIEM.

Comment: Thanks, revised the question with example

Answer (score 0):

Got it working

The protocol uses a basic /r/n to terminate the stream, which I had tried in the past.  The real trick lies with the Splunk configuration.  One needs to create a config files called props.conf and included the following line

> SHOULD_LINEMERGE=false

Then everything works fine.